# $(\text{even}/\text{even})\times \text{even} = \text{odd}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, parity, relation-algebra

> Do even natural numbers $e_1,e_2,e_3$ exist with $\frac{e_1}{e_2}\cdot e_3=o$, such that $o$ is an odd natural number?

If exist do they have any relation for this even tuple$(e_1,e_2,e_3)$?

Comment: (even / even) * even is even if and only if (even / even) is integer.

Comment: @barak it can be true even if it isn't an integer.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Correct!!!

Comment: @kvk30: What I said is not true (in particular, the "if and only if" part). I'm leaving it here for people to read and learn (and also for the comment-thread to make sense).

Comment: Write $e_1=2^{k_1}q_1;\ e_2=2^{k_2}q_2;\ e_3=2^{k_3}q_3$ with $q_1,q_2,q_3$ odd numbers. The condition is: *if and only if* $$\begin{cases}k_1+k_3=k_2\\ q_2\mid q_1q_3\end{cases}$$

Comment: It was written in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $v(n)$ denotes the exponent in the power of $2$ in the prime factorization of the even number $n$ ,

then
$\frac{e_1}{e_2}\cdot e_3$, if it is an integer, is odd if and only if $v(e_1)+v(e_3)=v(e_2)$.

The easiest example is $\frac{2}{4}\cdot 2$

Answer (score 2):

If $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$ are even and $o$ is odd, then:$$(e_1/ e_2)e_3=o\iff e_1\cdot e_3=o\cdot e_2\implies e_2\equiv0\bmod 4.$$

On the other hand, if $o$ is odd and $e_2\equiv 0\bmod 4$, then:
$$o\cdot e_2\equiv 0\bmod 4\implies \exists e_1,e_3\text{ even, such that } o\cdot e_2=e_1\cdot e_3\iff (e_1/e_2)e_3=o.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple counterexample: (4/8)*6=3.

Comment: "Counterexample" is for disproving an assertion. Not for exploring a question, unless you yourself make an assertion in the process.

Comment: Moreover, the OP explicitely asks for a general answer and not an example.